# R: What does the dot mean in the merge function?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am working on a R project, and I am trying to create a new dataset. I have the following code, which is based on an existing example:

```
data_new <- data %>%
            group_by(interval) %>%
            summarise(avg = mean(steps, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
            merge(data, ., all.x = TRUE)
```

For the above code, in the last line with the `merge()` function, the second parameter is a dot `(.)`. However, I am not sure what this dot means. Any insights are appreciated.

Comment: dot refers to the object on left hand side of the pipe i.e `data %>% group_by(interval) %>%  summarise(avg = mean(steps, na.rm = TRUE))` in this case.

Comment: You could probably simplify that code a bit using `mutate()` instead of `summarise` + `merge`.

Comment: As Ronak said, the dot notation (`.`) is a placeholder for the object passed into the function by the pipe. By default, `data %>% function()` places the `data` as the first argument in `function()`, which is equivalent to `data %>% function(.)` and `function(data)`. However, sometimes you need to pass `data` in as the second argument, and you do that with `.` like so: `data %>% function(some_object, .)`.